# Get a different size of Image thumbnail while working with custom metabox

Tags: customization, metabox, thumbnails, images

I am using custom metabox for a page in my new project, I am using it for uploading image, and attaching it to the page. It's working fine, I can select image or upload the image using WordPress' native uploader, and attach it. The issue is that I am getting the large size image only.

What happens is I have to resize it by specifying its width and height. Is there any way to get the other sizes of the uploaded or selected images via WordPress native uploader.

I know I can get the thumbnails by using `wp_get_attachment_image_src` function, but in order to work with this function I have to get attachment_id, I don't have it.

What I have is only image url. I don't know whether I am missing it somewhere or not.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: @s_ha_dum :  m using this code to get repeating fields -  https://gist.github.com/helenhousandi/1593065

Answer (score 0):

use this one and follow the structures

```
  $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ); 
 $imgarr = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id,'medium'); 
 echo $imgarr[0];/*it will return image url in medium size*/
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of your code. Links to the Codex entries for those functions would be helpful too.

Comment: k, Using the above said script(github) I have added a repeatable field group with a text box and a image upload button, using wordpress native media uploader i can upload image and I am storing uploaded images url inside the corresponding text box. So what I want is I want to access the other sizes of images That might have been created while I upload image using the wp native media uploader, imean thumbnails, or other sizes.to access images i am using <?php $images= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'repeatable_fields', true);?>,it returns an multidimensional array. so here i want to get smaller sizes

Comment: @s_ha_dum - plz see this question, this exactly i want to achieve - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487444/wordpress-image-size-based-on-url    -   besides resizing and all, is there any possibility to get the wordpress cropped versions of images

Comment: @PradiptaSarkar : Edit your answer with that information please.